# Have all Noether Charges been enumerated?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Noether's theorem states that every symmetry (of a Lagrangian) is associated with a conserved quantity.

Is it possible to know whether or not all symmetries (of the Lagrangians we use) have been enumerated? Or is it possible that someone will discover a new one?